# Modifying the shape for a subset of points with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to plot a large scatter plot that varies along a large number of dimensions.

Here's my starting plot:

```
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, shape=cyl, colour=gear, size=carb)) +
      geom_point()
```

[image: Sample plot with multiple variables]

Using the `mtcars` dataset, I'm simply including various shapes, colours, and sizes.  Now what i'd like to add to this is some distinguishing mark around all points with carb==8.  For example, add in a big black circle around these points.

Doing

```
p + geom_point() + geom_point(colour="black", shape=1, size=5)
```

is close in that it gets the circles as I want, but all points get circles, I want to instead limit this to just some of the points.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for this problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of initially putting your variables within the ggplot function, try to map your variables individually for every layer you add.

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars)+
geom_point(aes(wt, mpg, shape=as.factor(cyl), colour=gear, size=carb))+
geom_point(aes(wt[carb==8], mpg[carb==8]), colour="black", shape=1, size=7)
```

[image: img]

Comment: Good. Personally, I tend to pass the desired subset of the original data to the geom, like `geom_point(data = subset(mtcars,carb == 8),aes(...))`, and given the OP's code that possibility it probably worth pointing out.

Comment: Awesome! That's _exactly_ what I was looking for, and it's super simple.  Thanks!

Comment: As a subquestion, How can I edit the legend to signify that the black circles are around carb=8?